# How do I do image plots in the gnuplot module for python?

Tags: python, gnuplot

I find the documentation of the [Gnuplot package](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) for python a bit lacking. I want to do image plots like [this simple one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZIpu.png):

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

plot '-' matrix with image
4 4 4 1
3 2 1 1
1 2 3 1
0 0 0 0
e
```

How do I create the matrix and tell Gnuplot.py how to use it and do the image plot? I'd assume it to be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Gnuplot as gp
import numpy as np

g = gp.Gnuplot(debug=1)

m = np.matrix('4 4 4 1; 3 2 1 1; 1 2 3 1; 0 0 0 0')
gdat = gp.GridData(m, with_='matrix image', binary=0)

g.plot(gdat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnuplot-py is a very minimalistic wrapper around gnuplot, so you must give a lot of raw commands. Try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Gnuplot as gp
import numpy as np

g = gp.Gnuplot(debug=1)

m = np.matrix('4 4 4 1; 3 2 1 1; 1 2 3 1; 0 0 0 0')
gdat = gp.GridData(m, inline=True, binary=False)
g('set style data image')
g.plot(gdat)
```

I cannot test this at the moment, but it should get you started.

Comment: Hello, fellow Christoph. With gnuplot 4.6, I got the `Gnuplot.Errors.OptionError: binary inline data not supported` error. So I edited your answer to include `binary=False`. Now it is tested and works. Hope you don't mind.